# regex to remove hyperlinks

Tags: regex, grep

Input:
source http://www.emaxhealth.com/1275/misdiagnosing from here  http://www.cancerresearchuk.org/about-cancer/type recounting her experiences and thoughts blog   http://fty720.blogspot.com  even carried the new name. She was far from home.

From  the about input I want to remove the hyperlinks. Below is the regex that I am trying

`http://[\w|\W|\d|\s]*(?=[ ])`

This regex will encompass all characters,digits and whitespaces after encountering the word **'http'** and will continue till first blank space.
Unfortunately, it is not working as expected. Please do help me find out my error.Thanks

Comment: A better regex would be `[a-z\-]+://[^ ]+`, but I'm not entirely if this fits your needs. A link can also be `https://....` or `ftp://....` and they are still valid accessible links over a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try this sed command

```
sed  's/http[^ ]\+//g' FileName
```

**Output :**

source  from here  recounting her experiences and thoughts blog  even carried the new name. She was far from home.

Answer (score 1):

To find the hyperlink use:

```
\b(https?)://[A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;-]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]
```

or:

---

If you want to find the html a tag use:

```
<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)</a>
```

Comment: What about `http://@`?  With your regex, it is the minimum valid url. In my opinion, don't enforce a format and just burminate them all! And your's fails to URL that aren't in capitals.

Comment: @Andie2302 :The above regex works perfectly Thanks a lot. But shouldn't it match till the end of input text ?